# Powershell regex capture until "blank line"

Tags: regex, powershell

Here is the current script:

```
$VPLEX = plink 192.168.1.235 -l service -pw Mi@Dim7T ./health

$regex = '(?ms)Clusters:(.+?)Meta Data:'
$VPLEX = $VPLEX -join "`r`n"
$VPLEX_Clusters = [regex]::Matches($VPLEX,$regex) | foreach {$_.groups[1].value}
```

This successfully catches everything between "Clusters:" and "Meta Data:"

Here is part of the output (with the part I wish to capture highlighted)
[image]

This works perfectly except sometimes the output changes and "Meta Data:" is no longer there. I'd like to be able to capture until the first blank line, or from my highlighting maybe first line with just 1 space and nothing else.

I tried using the following to capture until newline but it did not work.

```
 $regex = '(?ms)Clusters:(.+?) \n'
```

Any help would be great, this is probably more simple than I think.

Comment: It's not wise to post a real working password in the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
$regex = '(?ms)Clusters:(.+?)\r\n\s*\r\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to detect the first instance of double linebreak (remember to exclude the first instance between "Cluster" and "Cluster Name"), like:

```
$regex = '(?ms)(Clusters:.+?Cluster.+?)[\n\r]{2,}\s*[\n\r]'
```